# Updating Kernel destroyed display drivers. Reverting back didn't help

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, display

recently reading an OMG Ubuntu post, decided to try the new 18.04.02  **4.18 Kernel** (https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/02/ubuntu-18-04-2-lts-released) by installing the packages to my 18.04.01 with the current 4.15 Kernel. However this destroyed my display prop drivers, (installed from https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa), so I removed them. However even after uninstalling them my display kept bugging. Ubuntu's nightlight didn't work, neither did the brightness settings.

Loosing all hope I **reverted back to the 4.15 Kernel however the problem persists**... I have no nvidia prop drivers installed currently, I have the old 4.15 Kernel, and the problem persists.

In order to understand the problem I wanted to ask several questions:

1) What are the default Ubuntu graphic drivers, and why do they break after updating the Kernel? How can I reinstall them? Where can I check if they are blacklisted?

2) General question, but **will the packages build for 18.04.`02` run on 18.04.`01` system**? If not how can I install an older version of any package when the apt tool shows only the newest version? For example right now I am with 18.04.01 but I see that the nvidia-drivers are version .02. Will this be a problem for my system?

Sorry if you find my lack of knowledge on the subject and my actions irritating, but that's Linux, we learn through breaking stuff!

Answer (score 1):

Each Nvidia proprietary driver supports some Linux kernels (up to some version). It is not guaranteed that they will build on newer ones.

Officially supported Nvidia drivers are located in Ubuntu repositories.

"Graphics Drivers" PPA is unofficial source of Nvidia drivers. Building on a specific HWE kernel is not guaranteed. Nothing is guaranteed at all when using PPA in general.

If you install unsupported driver, it is possible that it won't be quite easy to revert.

Having different HWE kernel versions for the same release complicates things a lot.

General recommendation is to use officially supported Nvidia drivers unless you have enough knowledge.

Comment: Hey Pilot6. Thanks for the feedback! I always go for the official repo, unless in my case the official drivers didn't work at all. I was stuck in gdm loop and the system just refused to start GNOME3. That's the only reason I went for the ppa drivers, that worked fine. Until I did the damage by upgrading the Kernel.  Now that I downgraded and removed all PPA drivers the problem persists. I have no NVIDIA PPA drivers, nor HWE Kernel, my hope is just finding the problem and solving it.

Comment: I am afraid a fresh install will be a solution in this case. It may take forever to find what is the real problem.

Comment: Reinstalling is the easiest I can do, however I want to take my chances and learn something new over how the system works. If you have any possible solutions in mind feel free to suggest them. All best!

Comment: This is not the best issue to learn on. It may be some bad packaging of the driver, a kernel bug, etc. I have some knowledge, but I am not sure that I can fix every specific case. Backup your system before playing with kernels or drivers.